# Could Magento share the only available database with wordpress when the two are hosted with different domains?

Tags: wordpress, hosting, blog

In godaddy, I am trying to install magento corresponding to my main domain `www.shoppox.com` and simultaneously wordpress corresponding to my *subdomain* `blog.shoppox.com`.

Could I do this if I have already purchased a hosting plan with single database because each one is requiring a separate database ?

Please suggest a way out (I don't want to spend more in upgrading my hosting plan).

Answer (score 0):

Yes Of course you can, while installing magento, on the installation screen where it asks for the db credentials here is a field named "Tables Prefixes", add a prefix for magento and it will up and running without any problem.

Comment: if this helped please mark this as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can install both with same database you have to add prefix to tables name
E.g.   Database name : your database name 
Password : your password
These credentials will be Used for both . When you install both these is option to add prefix to tables so you just add prefix (magento ,Wordpress) whatever you want